# Debugging ajax flow

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, asynchronous

I am really confused on a program that I made. A few days ago, it was working just fine, but now I am having problems with initializing it. I think I've figured out the source of the problem is basically the flow of the program is out of order but I have no idea why. Anybody have any idea how to debug this?

Debug Call Stack:

This

```
   function init() {
        createKeyArray();
        createData();
   }
```

Or this (createKeyArray)

```
function createKeyArray(){
     $.getJSON("reps.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            console.log(key);
            keyarray.push(key);
        });
    })
    .fail(function(){
    console.log("JSON extraction failed.");
    });
};
```

Now during this period on the `createKeyArray` this is where it gets really confusing, it goes to `.getJSON`, runs it, then goes to my `createData` function (skipping the `$.each` function that pushes everything into keyarray.

It then runs `createData` then goes BACK to the `.each` part of `createArray` function, runs that and then finishes running the rest of the program.

I am extremely confused whats going on and how to solve it. Appreciate any advice.

Comment: AJAX is _asynchronous_. You're calling `createData` before the callback function in `createKeyArray` runs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

I got it but thanks for the help everyone. I was just confused over how async worked. I had looked it up before posting this but I guess I ultimately didn't understand how it worked. The .getJSON method I redid, and this time I made it

```
function createKeyArray() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "sdf.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                keyarray.push(val);
            });
        }});
}
```

To be honest, I'm still not quite certain how the runtime for async operations works. I guess what I'm hinting at is if anybody could enlighten me how how the computer determines when to run the call back function on an asynchronous call, I would appreciate the insight. Otherwise, the above code is the answer.